# How do pizza parlors prevent the dough from puffing up?

Tags: pizza, crust

I tried to cook a pizza in two steps as recommended by some, whereby you first cook the crust, then add the toppings and cook again. However, the crust puffed up when I cooked it, so it was unusable.

When pizza parlors make pizza does the presence of the sauce and toppings somehow prevent the bread from puffing up, or do they do something else to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4):

No restaurant I’ve ever seen pre-bakes pizza crusts. As you’ve said, the toppings prevent the middle from rising.

Additionally, depending on the type of pizza, air bubbles from the middle of the crust may have been systematically pushed out to the edges, increasing the rise there while decreasing it in the center. And for thin crust pizza, a [docker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roller_docker) may have been used to minimize rising in the center.

Comment: I never knew that was called a "docker". But pretty much the same tool is used in Matzah production to help prevent rising.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally do this when making pizzas and the two methods I use to prevent it being an issue are;

Cook the dough with no toppings and either dock the dough before hand or just puncture it after wards to let the air out. You should only need to cook the base for a few minutes to ensure it is fully cooked before the toppings burn so I find this is usually more than enough.

The other method I use is to put the sauce on but nothing else. This weighs the dough down enough to prevent it rising and being an issue and doesn't significantly effect the taste. I feel it also leads to a more traditional feeling end result. I think this is the method used for shop bought frozen pizzas as the bases are cooked but the toppings clearly added afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I did this this last night, with a 2½ minute pre-cook. It puffed up like a balloon.

But there was nothing wrong with its eating qualities.

Before taking it out from the pre-cook, I used my pizza peel to press the air out, then topped it.  In the proper cooking step I had bubbles in the dough, but not problematic ones.

If you use a long pre-cook, you won't be able to press the air out, but 2-3 minutes is enough to ensure a crisp base.  This was on a stone at 240 °C.  Yesterday my stone was very well preheated, but often it's probably not fully up to temperature (when there's not long enough between when I get in from work and when I want to eat).  That's a large part of why I habitually pre-cook the base.  Another part of why I pre-cook is to get the puffing up out of the way before adding things that would slide off.  Sauce and toppings aren't really enough to stop an un-docked base puffing up.